# Java and C integration - running an app

Tags: java, c

I need your help. I have a C executable called "generator.out" that is a main() function that receives int argc and char * argv[]. The arguments for this main function are a file (let's call it sample.da) and a target file (let's call it out.bn). I need to create a java interface that can read those names (sample.da and out.bn) and run my function. The code I have so far is:

```
package swingapps;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;


public class Swingapps {
private JButton button = new JButton("Generate Bayesian Network");
private JTextField path=new JTextField(40);
private JTextField name=new JTextField(40);
public Swingapps(JPanel jp) {
    jp.add(button);
    jp.add(path);
    jp.add(name);
    button.addActionListener(new Handler());
    path.addActionListener(new Read());
    name.addActionListener(new Call());
}
String text;
private class Read implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    text = path.getText();
    path.selectAll();
}
}

String namet;
private class Call implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    namet = name.getText();
    path.selectAll();
}
}
File filep=new File("text"+File.separator+"text");
File filen=new File("namet"+File.separator+"namet");

private class Handler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
        Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/user/workspace/proj2/./generator.out");
        }
        catch(IOException ioex)
        {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Contador               ");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    frame.setContentPane(p);
    p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Swingapps app = new Swingapps(p);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Please note that I'm a newbie in java so I don't understand very much of this. I just need a simple interface to run this program!

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the real question ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to run my generator.out app from a Java interface, using as arguments the strings text and namet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, here's an example that could fit your situation :

```
String command = "generator.out";
String arg1    = "sample.da";
String arg2    = "out.bn";
java.io.File workinDir = new java.io.File("/tmp");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command, arg1, arg2);
pb.directory(workinDir);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: thanks, but it says that the argument of "directory()" cannot be a String, only a File, what should I do?

Comment: Ok thanks, but could you just answer me one more thing? I now have the process p, but what should I do so that my button executes p when I click it? Shouldn't it be just this, adding the ActionListener? Is there anything I should do to run the java program? I'm using Eclipse and just clicking the "Run" button

Comment: To execute the process when the user press the button you have to add the above code into the actionlister as you already did in your question's code . To run the program outside eclipse you can simply copy the generated class files(usually under bin folder) or create a jar executable from eclipse export menu ...

Comment: I tried all that and it didn't work, is it possible to create the jar file, paste it in the same folder as my C app and run it from there? Because like this I wouldn't have to change my directory. Also should I work with the chmod to allow the C app to be executed?

Comment: Too many questions in comments, open new question for your other inquiries ... However yes you can generate a jar file, copy it into the same location of the c program .

Answer (score 0):

Just add the arguments as you would do it on the commandline:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "/home/user/workspace/proj2/./generator.out sample.da out.bn");
```

Sometimes it works better using the method taking the different parts as an array:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[] {"/home/user/workspace/proj2/./generator.out",
        "sample.da", "out.bn"}):
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I want to use my string from getText() I should just replace "sample.da" with text (no "")?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say there, bad formatting? You can of course change those to text from a textfield.